# is it "Graphic Design" or is it "Adobe Graphic Design"?

Tags: discussion

Someone asks a [brand-agnostic question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101272/correct-and-simple-way-to-convert-png-to-svg), and there are four "Close as duplicate" votes that redirect to a question which is specifically about Adobe Illustrator, while this answer may not be acceptable to the OP for various reasons (money, beliefs, operating system....).

Comment: Personally I don't agree with this question being a duplicate... but I would've closed it as Primarily Opinion Based for the same reason as Wrzlprmft's comment.

Comment: Given that there was an accepted answer with 4 upvotes shows this could have been misguided.

Comment: That answer is opinion based as is the question. What makes that method best? I could offer faster solutions. I could offer more accurate solutions. So in what way is that best? Upvotes doesn't change that the question is opinion based.

Comment: What makes the method best? Like on every SE site, the number of upvotes. If there were only one possible answer to each question we would not have a voting system, would we?

Comment: There can be more than one answer but there must be criteria to determine best. That is an issue of the question not the answers. If I ask "What PC is best for graphic design?" You might say a Supercomputer, someone else may say a Macbook, and another may say a Surfacebook. Without criteria in the question there is no way to select which is best beyond personal preference. The person didn't specify if they're looking for the fastest method, or the cheapest method, or the most accurate method, or anything else. Without that criteria its not an answerable question.

Comment: Maybe you are reading too much into "best". The question was answered and accepted, therefore it was answerable. No question is perfect, by the time you have made it perfect you have the answer...

Comment: I think you are missing the bigger picture.  SE seeks questions that in fact can be answered for the questioner.  Not broad answers and a collection of full blown tutorials because the questioner decided to not go into detail.  We are not a tutorial request site but while some answers do have some tutorials in them that doesn't mean we allow questions when someone just asks how do I do X with no supporting effort or application clarity.

Comment: If an Adobe solution is not acceptable to OP I think it's OP's responsibility to specify that in their question: "I'm looking to do X,Y, and Z in *Inkscape*"

Comment: @Mentalist would "with FLOSS" or "without Adobe" also be ok in your view?

Comment: @Nemo Yes, that would also be fine. Anything to communicate clearly *the criteria of the question* so that others don't waste their time composing an answer that isn't relevant to OP, and also to prevent the question from being closed as a duplicate when OP doesn't consider it to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If it may be useful to someone else it should be noted in the comments.  If you're unsure then I would suggest creating a comment under the question asking what they seek in the form of application.

Or, you could provide your variation as another user has but in Inskape.  If enough people vote on it then they see it as a duplicate.

Either way, this is an example of why a question should be closed for lack of effort and not shown.  There are a multitude of optional answers people can post but for us to actually be able to provide an accurate answer to the question there are more variables needed to solve the equation.

Comment: Putting a comment that there is an answer with Adobe software is one thing, but closing the question **because** it has an answer with Adobe software (and thus implying it has no other possible answer) shows that you are seeing GD through Adobe glasses... From that point of view you are giving an answer to my initial question...

Comment: Um..  don't follow.  The answer posted was from inskape but the linked question was for Adobe.  Regardless of the software the question was asked before so was closed as a dup so it would be linked for future reference.  As mentioned if the op could make an edit with further detail we could reopen it.  Don't see how any of that said indicates I just thinks it's an adobe question.  Frankly it's a bad question with no effort.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not adobe support. However it may be a mistake to not atleast mention what you consider a proper software. Graphics Designers work with adobe applications, sorry, they have to. Adobe has made most of the infrastructure in the digital publishsing industry. And to be compatible with your peers you are pretty much forced to have adobe software installed. This is a sad thing but its a fact. And for most graphics designers that would be best, not discussing the merits of other software.*

Therefore suggesting a person to use Illustrator over say [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net) (which is what inkscape uses) is probably the expected answer. I mean hell you could use mathematica for this.  So best in thsi case is wide.

Is it a dupe, no not really. Things happen.

Comment: This is "Graphics Design" but not "Professional Graphics Design". The first sentence of the help reads "*Graphic Design SE is for questions targeted toward design professionals, students, and **enthusiasts**.*".

Comment: FWIW: As a multi-decade graphic designer, illustrator, technical illustrator, and at one time Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop instructor... I dumped Adobe from my freelance practice and switched to Affinity Designer and Affinity Photo some time ago and have, so far, not encountered a situation in which I felt a need to re-examine that decision.

Comment: @GerardFalla it will eventually happen adobe being its own worst enemy. Unfortunately Affinity Designer failed to implement the only part i really need ;)